# How to use "AND" as not boolean operator, but just query string in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I want to use "AND" as just query string, not boolean operator, but lucene always recognize it as boolean operator.

For example, I want to query "AND" in order to find "GRIEVE HORNER AND ASSOCIATES" as below.

```
Query query = QueryParser.parse("AND");
```

However, lucene gives error, said

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'AND': Encountered " <AND> "AND "" at line 1, column 0.
```

How can I use string "AND" as query string, not boolean operator?
Since my search system is to find company name, "AND" is not considered as stop words.

I tried to use

```
QueryParser.escape(query_str)
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping it in quotes should do the trick, such as:

```
queryparser.parse("\"AND\"");
```